# Parameters in comparing OpenCL and CUDA programs

Tags: performance, cuda, profiling, opencl

I have written a scientific program in CUDA and OpenCL. All I want to do is to compare the runtime performance of these programs together. What parameters should I consider while analyzing the performance comparison? The time taken is one of the parameters. What are the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few metrics I consider useful are

1. **Occupancy** - You need to ensure that occupancy is maximized for all your target deployment platforms (GPU, CPU and/or implementation).
2. **Throughput** - You can calculate your maximum compute throughput using modified kernels that zero out any latency essentially making your kernel compute-bound.
3. **Latency** - Again - tweak your kernels to perform (very little to) no computations and test the performance. This will indicate how the various kinds of memories being accessed affect your kernel and its performance.

Any other parameters will probably depend on your application's decision factors, I guess. For example, how does it scale will be related to the question - does your application need to scale up at all? And so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could compare power consumption. The amount of time it took to write the code in each might also be of interest, since it reflects on the total cost of the project. If the code runs on different hardware, the cost of the hardware could also be included. Combined, the numbers could give you the total cost of implementation and operation for each solution.